# Normalize the position of a transform rotate element with transform translate

Tags: css, math, sass, styling

I was in my last years still not able to find a solution, to `normalize` element positions, after i rotate them.

Here is my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9n8zaq

It's about positioning the upper `<div>` with `transform` so that the yellow lower cut edge at each resolution is exactly where the two red lines meet. (Changes the view width.) If the cut edge of the yellow element does not conform to the red line collision point at any width, the formula is wrong)

The `width` and `height` I have set to double the value of, otherwise this would not fill the full `height` and `width` by the rotate. width and height should therefore remain at these values.

Solely changed, should `transform: rotate (-10deg) translate (-25%, calc (-50% - 10%));` in the class `.view-area-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transform: translate(-25%, -50.77%) rotate(-10deg) ;
```

The horizontal `-25%` brings the box back to the horizontal midline. The vertical `-50.77%` positions the lower edge onto the red cross. The number is `50.77% = 50% / cos(10°)`.

Here is another variant that keeps the center of the lower edge on the cross:

```
transform: translate(-25%, -50%) translate(0, 50%) rotate(-10deg) translate(0, -50%);
```

The first translation moves the center of the lower edge onto the cross (without any rotation). The next three transforms are a rotation about the center of the lower edge (translate to the pivot point, rotate, translate back). Of course, you can combine the first two translations, but this will make it a bit harder to read.

Comment: For everyone who need to calculate this dynamicly in sass direct: https://github.com/terkel/mathsass

Comment: I try to center the text: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9n8zaq?file=style.scss But i dont understand what i need to do to center it... when i remove the rotate its perfect centered =/